# How to Launch Default Browser to Open Local .html File

Tags: windows, browser, cmd, default, file-uri

The default browser can be called to open an URL (http,https) through explorer.exe in cmd terminal:

```
> explorer https://google.com
```

However, .html files on my machine are already assigned to be opened using an editor, and Explorer will open HTML files in editor. For example, these will open editor:

```
> explorer test.html
> explorer file:///C:/Temp/test.html
```

How to open `local HTML files` in `cmd` using `default browser`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try the `start` command:

```
start file://C:/Temp/test.html
```

Comment: this is because the file association for .html is set to your editor.  there are lots of ways to fix this.  an easy way: in explorer, right click on an html file; select Open With; select Choose another app; click the checkbox "always use this app to open html files" and select your browser from the list.

Comment: uhm, but my editor should still bind to .html file type, i need to edit them

Comment: the file association controls what happens when you double click a file. you can still edit the html file from the editor: by passing it in on the command line, by doing a File Open, or by dragging the file into the editor.